# Matrix Transpose using R t() function

Tags: r, matrix, transpose

For following argument

```
x <- c(1,3,4,24,1,2,2,2,1,3,3,1,1,0,8) 
A <- matrix(x,nrow = 5)
n <- ncol(A)
t(A)
meancol <- colMeans(A)
meancol
t(t(meancol))
```

I am writing to ask why for `t(A)`, I only need put `t()` to get what I want, but for meancol,I need to put `t(t())` to get the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the output of `meancol <- colMeans(A)` isn't a matrix, then the function transpose interprets it as a vector.

From the `Details` of the function `t()` we have:

> **Details** This is a generic function for which methods can be written.
> The description here applies to the default and "data.frame" methods.
>
> A data frame is first coerced to a matrix: see as.matrix. When x is a
> vector, it is treated as a column, i.e., the result is a 1-row matrix.

The vector is read as a 1-column matrix, therefore the result is a 1-row matrix.

Comment: thank u. But I have to point out ```t(t(meancol))``` returns the column vector.

Comment: Exactly. `meancol` is a vector  and is just interpreted as a column by `t()`, therefore `t(meancol)` is a row. `t(t(meancol)` is then a column